# Airtags and flying safety

Tags: safety

The TSA allows Airtags in checked and hand-on luggage. Is this the case too for all civil aviation authorities (EU for example)? It has a  coin-shaped CR2032 battery and a range of 800 feet low energy Bluetooth.

Comment: 800 feet? Really? I mean, if the receiver is at the center of a 50' parabolic dish antenna pointed right at the device, maybe, but for a more normal Bluetooth receiver, 800' is pretty far, especially if that watch battery needs to last more than a few hours. In any event, @MichaelHall is right and this should be migrated to Travel.SE.

Comment: @RalphJ BT **5** LE is actually capable of such ranges (and [long battery life](https://www.onsemi.com/company/news-media/blog/iot/bluetooth-low-energy-wireless-protocols-battery-life)) although there are conflicting reports whether the Apple AirTag itself is.

Comment: It was not allowed before?

Comment: You won't find an answer. Batteries are allowed, on radios everyone _official_ is mum and just look the other way.